# handling the creation of an object,which has a child ( ~ a collection of entities probably 1000000 or more)

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, spring-batch

I'm facing some problems in handling the creation or the modification of an object,which has a child (a collection of entities(possibly 1000000 or more)) in a batch.

in the beginning, i tried to create the object directly :

```
entite.getEntiteManager(session).createEntite(entite);
```

But, an exception of :

```
maximum open cursors exceeded was thrown.
```

So, I tried the second method: I create the father firstly, than I create the children by list of 250 and I affect the reference of the father to them than I commit. And that's work Now.

the problem is: if some trouble raised during the creation of children so it rollback only the list wich has faced the problem. The others are already commited.

Could Spring Batch be useful form me in this case. Does he treat this issue.

Comment: This is why I hate ORMs. They have their role, but they are not designed for the purpose of bulk updates of millions of rows.  You will be pulling your hair out forever to try to force-fit this.  Write a stored proc or some other SQL call out to do a native SQL update.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i'm thinking to do a sort of temporary table to store the information until i finish than commit to the real table.?

Comment: DO NOT USE ORM FOR BATCH WORK.  This is like using a spoon to dig the Panama Canal.

Comment: Regarding using a temp table - YES!  YES!!  YES!!!  If you're working in a relational database it's best to think about tables, joins, views - i.e. relational operations.  This is what the database is optimized for.  Adding in an ORM and a bunch of objects (fine things, objects - won't say a word against them - some of my best friends are objects :-) is just piling on a bunch of layers which are unhelpful (IMO) in a batch environment.  Tables, views, joins - that's the ticket!

Comment: The object model probably shouldn't have the parent->Child relationship mapped if the collection is going to contain a million entities. You can always query for the children directly and use a cursor or pagination if it is needed, and only have the child->parent relationship mapped.  Second, EclipseLink allows batching.  Call em.flush() and em.clear() to manage memory.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_(ELUG)#How_to_Use_Batch_Writing_for_Optimization and http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/config/FlushClearCache.html for

Comment: Even if i use the flush() and clear() methods, i got the same problem; that if i don't commit in between batch size, the persist() method lunch a "maximum open cursors exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Batch 'chunking' concept will support your retry and failure scenario as you've described.  That is, you've created 500 records and a failure occurs and you don't want to lose what you've already got when you restart.

A simple configuration for such a job might be as follows;

```
<batch:job id="entityCreationJob">
    <batch:step id="entityCreationJob.step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="entityReader" writer="entityWriter" commit-interval="250"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

This simple configuration will do the following;
- read/create a single record 'per row' `(entity.getEntityManager(session).createEntity(e))`
- 'commit' the record in 250 record blocks (set by the commit interval)

should you have a failure (lets say, at record 1190), with a commit interval of 250, you will only 'lose' the work of 190 records.  the previous 1000 have been committed already to the database.  when the application restarts, it will pick up at the 1001 record and continue, committing in 250 record blocks.

to make best use of the commit/retry component, i would suggest you use the `JpaItemWriter` and either the `JpaTransactionManager` or a JTA Transaction Manager.